# How to delete table row without cascade option in Laravel 5 (Query Builder)

Tags: php, mysql, html, laravel

I want to delete table row, without cascade. I use existing database, so table create using cascade on. But i want to delete only one table row , without cascading.

Now when I run this code  it delete other table value too. (when i delete `commitee_member` table row , it automatically delete `commitee` table detail too. )

```
 CommiteeMember::where('commiteeId', '=', $commiteeId)->where('memberId', '=', $memberId)->delete();
```

If there any way to do it ? please , hope some one help.